# Can you make your dreams come true?

Tags: robot-unicorn-attack

I gave this platformer another try today. [Damn you, Daniel.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/482509#482509) Luckily I fared bad enough that I quickly gave up — I mean, I couldn't even make my dreams come true!

I then turned on Youtube looking for videos of impressive runs by people <s>with too much time on their hands</s> trying harder than me, and found a few, like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUR-ECcHTJc). However, even their 250k points games didn't result in a wish coming true.

Does this game have a end? Can you win?

Comment: You won the second you picked up Robot Unicorn Attack.

Comment: I'm actually trying to ruin it by becoming a mod myself @badp ;-)

Comment: @Ivo irrelevant :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nope, you can't win this game. The end is when you lose. Even the song doesn't end, it just keeps looping, and it's really addictive!

The point is pretty much just racking up the highest score you can, or trying to beat your friends score.

Comment: Unless of course your dream is to play an awesome game and hear a catchy tune.

Comment: Always / I want to be with you / and make believe with you / and live in harmony, harmony, oh love

Answer (score -1):

It's just forever. It's like a circle.. You just keep on going.. Dying.. Respawning... Raging... Using your yellow shards for an extra life.. Spending your tear drops on new parts... So no, unless your wish was to beat your score, listen to a nice tune, or challenge friends, then your wish will not come true.

Comment: Hi Madelynn, welcome on Arqade. However, please keep in mind that this is not some kind of forum ; your answer doesn't add anything, and will probably deleted. Feel free to read the [Tour](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour), to learn how to improve this site ;)